# Problem cutting

Tags: boolean-modifier

[image]This crank was made from two cylinders and a cube joined as one piece. I popped in a bevel modifier and applied it, then went to cut a hole in one end.  The hole appeared as expected but the other end of the crank disappeared.

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot or share the file?

Comment: As @moonboots says we either need to see a screenshot (Window > Save Screenshot in Blender) or your blend file shared via https://blend-exchange.com/. It's possible that the normals are inverted on part of your object. Turn on the Face Orientation overlay on the Viewport Overlays menu. If any part of the object is red rather than blue go into Edit mode, Select All and then Shift-N to recalculate the normals.

Comment: Could you please share your file before you apply the boolean?